# Unable to upload pdf file: Php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf

The issue I'm facing is, I get the following error while trying to upload some pdfs `your upload file is not PDF file.`  However, this error doesn't show up for all pdfs, it's only for some pdf files I get this error.

```
<?php
$error = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];
//get upload file type
$type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
$action = "upload";
//get file name
$picname = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$nameArray = explode(".", $picname);
if {
    //check files
    //filetoUpload code
}
?>
```

The issue is that, in the `url: '../controller/uploadFile.php'`  even if the file is PDF, `$type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];` will return empty and then it will go into the condition `else if($type !="application/pdf" )` and pop up the alert  `your upload file is not PDF file.`. Like I said, this issue is with most of the pdf file. However, some pdf files manage to get uploaded without any issue and if a pdf file gets uploaded, then `$type` will be `application/pdf`.

Your input will be highly appriciated.

---UPDATE---
The issue is with `$_FILES`, it's not fetching the pdf file details for some reason
The issue has been resolved. I checked `'$error= $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'];` and the value was returning 1

````
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.```
````

Comment: This might be redundant, but you could also try checking the file's mime type with mime_content_type($picname) just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could better check the extension, this also prevents malicious users to upload exe or zip files when they provide the header `Content-Type: application/pdf`. Also not all browsers/api libraries specify a `Content-Type`.

If your filename does not contain a path, check it with a regex so people cannot upload files to directories they shouldn't (ex ../../cache/exe). use for example

`preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_+\\- ]+\\.pdf$/", $filename)` to check if it is a pdf.

Do never do `unlink('files/' . $filename);` when $filename could be anything submitted by the user. Delete `../index.php` could destroy your server.

Comment: I tried ```Content-Type: application/pdf``` and it didnt work. The issue is with ```$_FILES``` . Its not being able to even fetch the size of the file